# How to enable GCP service, I get a PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When I run `gcloud services enable service:container.googleapis.com`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.services.enable) PERMISSION_DENIED: Not found or permission denied for service(s): service:container.googleapis.com.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - subject: ?error_code=220002&services=service:container.googleapis.com
    type: googleapis.com
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: serviceusage.googleapis.com
  metadata:
    services: service:container.googleapis.com
  reason: SERVICE_CONFIG_NOT_FOUND_OR_PERMISSION_DENIED
```

What permission am I missing that's causing this error?

Comment: Hmm let's see if it's the `Not Found` that's causing the issue, or the `permission denied`. What do you see in the console? https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/container.googleapis.com

Comment: I was able to enable the service from console.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/enable), it should be like this :

`gcloud services enable [SERVICE_NAME]`

or

`gcloud services enable container.googleapis.com`

You can also see the list of available services for a project, run:

`gcloud services list --available`

and To list the services the current project has enabled, run:

`gcloud services list --enabled`

Comment: Confirmed. Running `gcloud services enable service:container.googleapis.com` gives me same error as OP (even though I have all IAM perms at organization level).  
Removing `service:` from the command successfully enables the service.

Answer (score 0):

I used below and it worked. I just used CONTAINER as service name rather than using container.googleapis.com

gcloud services enable container

Operation "operations/acf.p2-768261041254-0cc69e23-b9e8-449f" finished successfully.